# MVC how to return a view with a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

At the moment I have a Method that work, it is working when clicking a link here the code in Razor:

```
@Html.ActionLink("New User ,Register", "Register", new { OpenID = Model.OpenID })
```

I would like have the same effect with but returning the View from the Controller, at the moment I'm using this code with no success

```
return View("Register", lm);
```

I'm pretty new at MVC so I'm a bit confused. The view returned with my last code miss smt and I support is connected with the part `new { OpenID = Model.OpenID }`

Could you point me out in the right direction?

This how it is the method for my controller:

```
public ActionResult Register(string OpenID)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't understand what you're trying to do. Do you want to link a different view and pass some data to it?

Comment: I need call a different View and passing some data that OpenID = Model.OpenID as it would be when a user click the link

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5823518/40521) `ViewData` and `ViewBag` . try to use strongly typed `ViewModels`. That makes your code clean (*and the next developer who is gonna maintain your code, HAPPY*)

Have a Property called `OpenID` in your `ViewModel`

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
     //Other Properties also
     public string OpenID { set; get; }
}
```

Now you can set this value when returning the view, in your `action` method:

```
public ActionResult Register(string OpenId)
{
     var vm = new RegisterViewModel();
     vm.OpenID = OpenId;
     return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment in my specific case the Action Method to be called as this signature public ActionResult Register(string OpenID) could you post an example of code for me? thanks

Comment: I need smt like return ActionResult("Register", lm.OpenID); but in my case does not work any idea?

Answer (score 8):

You can add any data you want to a ViewBag variable.

In your controller you'd set the value as such.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    ViewBag.OpenID = OpenID;

    return View()
}
```

And in your razor view you can access it the same way

**MVC3 Razor View**

```
@ViewBag.OpenID
```

Comment: Helped me with the ViewBag.

Answer (score 4):

Please, take a look at this view (ViewA):

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("My link", "ViewB", new { someData = "some data I'm passing on" })
</div>
```

And these two actions:

```
    public ActionResult ViewA()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ViewB(string someData)
    {
        //Here someData has the value "some data I'm passing on"
        return View();
    }
```

We're just passing the values by get (that is, the query string). By matching the names, MVC is able to do the magic for us =)

Hope this helps.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I currently use this form:

```
return View("Name View", new { parameterName = Value})
```

Practical example:

```
return View("Register", new { OpenId = 1})
```